# display flex some columns side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to display four colums side by side. On smaller screens the colums should wrap and
should be arranged one below the other. But column 3 and 4 should always wrap around together.

So on smaller screens column 1 and 2 should be one below the other
colum 3 and 4 stand side by side below column 1 and 2

That is what I have, but this does not work:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.event-table 
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-top: 0.7%;
    padding-bottom: 0.7%;
}

.eventcell {
    background:#c2c2c2;
    padding-right:2%;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    flex-basis:50%;  
}

.eventcell:nth-of-type(3),
.eventcell:nth-of-type(4) {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="event-table">
    <div class="eventcell">BILD</div>
    <div class="eventcell">DATUM</div>
    <div class="eventcell">TITEL</div>
    <div class="eventcell">KAUFEN</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I wrap the entire page in a div.

```
<div class='some-page-wrapper'>
</div>
```

Then define a .row and .column class that can help with the layout.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Now if we want a two column layout:

```
<div class='some-page-wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='blue-column'>
        Some Text in Column One
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='green-column'>
        Some Text in Column Two
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.some-page-wrapper {
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.blue-column {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.green-column {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

What if you wanna add a third column? The HTML is easily updated to:

```
<div class='some-page-wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='blue-column'>
        Some Text in Column One
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='green-column'>
        Some Text in Column Two
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
      <div class='orange-column'>
        Some Text in Column Two
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="event-table">
    <div class="eventcell">BILD</div>
    <div class="eventcell">DATUM</div>
<div style="width:100%; display:flex; flex-wrap:no-wrap">
    <div class="eventcell">TITEL</div>
    <div class="eventcell">KAUFEN</div>
</div>
</div>
```